# Call SetTokenInformation always returns False

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, createprocess

I'm trying to create a new process using `CreateProcessWithTokenEx` on Session 1 using the following code (Powershell which runs C#):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR {
    public byte revision;
    public byte size;
    public short control;
    public IntPtr owner;
    public IntPtr group;
    public IntPtr sacl;
    public IntPtr dacl;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STARTUPINFO {
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
    public int length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}
public static class Kernel32 {

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr Thread, UInt32 Access, out IntPtr Handle);
        
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
        IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        int TokenType,
        int ImpersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);
        
        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(
        IntPtr hToken,
        short dwLogonFlags,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        int dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
        );
        
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public extern static bool SetTokenInformation(IntPtr handle, uint tokenInformationClass, IntPtr dwSessionId, uint tokenInformationLegnth);
    }

"@
$userProcess = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "explorer.exe"' | select -First 1
$marshal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]

$si = New-Object STARTUPINFO
$si.wShowWindow = 5
$si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\default"
$si.cb = $marshal::SizeOf($si)

$sd = New-Object SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
$sd.revision = 1
$sd.control = 4

$userToken = [IntPtr]0
$process = Get-Process -id $userProcess.ProcessId
$null = [kernel32]::OpenProcessToken($process.Handle, 2, [ref]$userToken)
$token = [IntPtr]0

$null = [kernel32]::DuplicateTokenEx($userToken, 0xFFFF, 0, 2, 1, [ref]$token)
$env = [intPtr]0

$null = [kernel32]::CreateEnvironmentBlock([ref]$env, $token, $false)

$dwSessionId = [IntPtr]1
$tokenSessionClassId = 12
[kernel32]::SetTokenInformation($token, $tokenSessionClassId, $dwSessionId, [IntPtr]::Size)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()

$pi = New-Object PROCESS_INFORMATION
$null = [kernel32]::CreateProcessWithTokenW($token, 1, "C:\windows\my.exe", $null, 0x0410, $env, "c:", [ref]$si, [ref]$pi)
```

The problem, my process created with SessionId=0 and not SessionId=1, When I'm trying to change the SessionId using `SetTokenInformation` The return value is always `False` and the return value of `GetLastWin32Error()` is [203-ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

What I'm doing wrong?

Is there is a better way to create a process on Session!=0 ?

**EDIT**: Not sure that the error code 203 is from `CreateProcessWithTokenW` function

Comment: `CreateProcessWithTokenW` internally set SessionId in token, based of caller process SessionId and you can not change this.

Comment: so your call `SetTokenInformation` with `TokenSessionId` anyway senseless in this case - it will be not have effect

Comment: *Is there is a better way to create a process on Session!=0 ?* use `CreateProcessAsUserW`

Comment: You are missing an environmental variable.  The process class has no environmental variable unless you set the variable.  Read the documentation on the executable you are running and see what environmental variables are needed.

Comment: @jdweng - *You are missing an environmental variable* - 100% no.

Comment: @RbMm : Why are you so sure I'm wrong?  The error message says "203-ERROR ENVVAR NOT FOUND".

Comment: @jdweng - i at very strong doubt that `SetTokenInformation` return this error (really it never return this error if no hook). and because i perfect know this topic. look like `$dwSessionId` pass value instead pointer of it. anyway, how i already say - use `SetTokenInformation` at all senseless in curreny context and `CreateProcessWithTokenW` wrong for task

Comment: @RbMm, Thanks for your reply, when I'm trying to use ```CreateProcessAsUserW($token, "C:\windows\my.exe","", 0,0,0,0x410,$env,"C:",[ref]$si,[ref]$pi)``` I got error code ```5``` which is ACCESS_DENIED (I have full permission to this file)

Comment: and why you decide that error related to file permission ?! `CreateProcessAsUserW` must be used

Comment: No, just thats what I though about the file permission, sorry, So what is the reason that I get error code 5? I'm running as NT-AUTHORITY/SYSTEM

Comment: fot instance - error from token  handle access. you not show your actual code. and why we must belive in that you post correct eror codes ? 203 - exactly not correct

Comment: @RbMm, just edit the code about the error, It's the same code except the replace of ```CreateProcessWithTokenW ``` with ```CreateProcessAsUserW ```

Comment: and ? what api call is fail with what error ? i bad understand *Powershell* so exactly can not say where error

Comment: @RbMm-  get error code 5 while calling to ```CreateProcessAsUserW```

Comment: you not post actual and exactly src or binary code, which possible check.  and because you wrong about error 203 may be you wrong and about error 5 (from which api call error or it value)

Comment: Have a look [PrimaryTokenTheft](https://github.com/slyd0g/PrimaryTokenTheft). It may be a current process privilege problem.